# How to filter a map comparing it with another collection

Tags: clojure

I have a map with collection of these `{:id 2489 ,values :.......} {:id 5647 ,values : .....}` and so on till 10000 and I want to filter its value dependent on another collection which has ids of first one like `(2489 ,......)`

I am new to clojure and I have tried :

```
(into {}  (filter #(some (fn [u] (= u (:id %))) [2489 3456 4567 5689]) record-sets))
```

But it gives me only the last that is 5689 id as output `{:id 5689 ,:values ....}`, while I want all of them, can you suggest what I can do.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you start out with a sequence of N maps, then you try to stuff them into a single map.  This will cause the last one to overwrite the first one.

Instead, you need to have the output be a sequence of M maps (M <= N). 
Something like this is what you want:

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :stuff :fred}
   {:id 2 :stuff :barney}
   {:id 3 :stuff :wilma}
   {:id 4 :stuff :betty}])

  (let [ids-wanted  #{1 3}
        data-wanted (filterv
                      (fn [item]
                        (contains? ids-wanted (:id item)))
                      data)]
    (println data-wanted))
```

with result:

```
[{:id 1, :stuff :fred} 
 {:id 3, :stuff :wilma}]
```

Be sure to use the Clojure CheatSheet:   http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html

I like `filterv` over plain `filter` since it always gives a non-lazy result (i.e. a Clojure vector).

Answer (score 1):

You are squashing all your maps into one. First thing, for sake of performance, is to change your list of IDs into a set, then simply filter.

```
(let [ids (into #{} [2489 3456 4567 5689])]
  (filter (comp ids :id) record-sets))
```

This will give you the sequence of correct maps. If you want to covert this sequence of maps into a map keyed by ID, you can do this:

```
(let [ids (into #{} [2489 3456 4567 5689])]
  (->> record-sets
       (filter (comp ids :id))
       (into {} (map (juxt :id identity)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this could be with the use of [select-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys) functions in Clojure

`select-keys` returns a map of only the keys given to the function

so given that your data is a list of maps we can convert it into a hash-map of ids using [group-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) and then call `select-keys` on it

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :stuff :fred}
   {:id 2 :stuff :barney}
   {:id 3 :stuff :wilma}
   {:id 4 :stuff :betty}])

(select-keys (group-by :id data) [1 4]) 
; => {1 [{:id 1, :stuff :fred}], 4 [{:id 4, :stuff :betty}]}
```

However now the values is a map of ids. So in order to get the orignal structure back we need get all the values in the map and then flatten the vectors

```
; get all the values in the map
(vals (select-keys (group-by :id data) [1 4]))
; => ([{:id 1, :stuff :fred}] [{:id 4, :stuff :betty}])

; flatten the nested vectors
(flatten (vals (select-keys (group-by :id data) [1 4])))
; => ({:id 1, :stuff :fred} {:id 4, :stuff :betty})
```

Extracting the values and flattening might seem a bit inefficient but i think its less complex then the nested loop that needs to be done in the filter based methods.

You can using the threading macro to compose all the steps together

```
(-> (group-by :id data)
    (select-keys [1 4])
    vals
    flatten)
```

Another thing that you can do is to store the data as a map of ids from the beginning this way using select keys wont require group-by and the result wont require flattening.

[Update all keys in a map](https://dzone.com/articles/clojure-apply-function-each)

```
(update-values (group-by :id data) first)
; => {1 {:id 1, :stuff :fred}, 2 {:id 2, :stuff :barney}, 3 {:id 3, :stuff :wilma}, 4 {:id 4, :stuff :betty}}
```

This would probably be the most efficient for this problem but this structure might not work for every case.